# HTML checbkox values to C# array

Tags: c#, html, checkbox

I have list of html checboxes in form and I need get checked checboxes values to C# array after form sent, it is possible?

```
 <form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    @foreach (var category in ViewBag.Categories)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Category" value=@category["UUID"] />@category["CategoryName"]<br /> //Generate >20 checkboxes
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
    <button type="submit" formmethod="post">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change following line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Category" value=@category["UUID"] />@category["CategoryName"]<br />
```

to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Category" value="@category["UUID"]"/>@category["CategoryName"]<br />
```

and now in your action you can get it from `Request` object or by adding a parameter of name `Category` to get in the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
   var checkedCategories = Request.Form["Category"];
}
```

or:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(int[] Category)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Category" value=@category["UUID"]  runat="server" />@category["CategoryName"]<br />
```

include runat="server"  in the input type. you can acess in the code  behind.

Comment: it is mvc not webforms